# Remove a child object in Fauna DB

Tags: javascript, facebook-fql, document-database, faunadb, jamstack

I need to remove a child object in FQL. Let me demonstrate with the following example:

```js
{
    "1": {
        "name": "test"
    },
    "2": {
        "name": "test2"
    }
}
```

And I want this JSON to look like this:

```js
{
    "1": {
        "name": "test"
    }
}
```

Is there an FQL function that could help me?

Comment: https://github.com/fauna-labs/todo-vanillajs/blob/main/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set a key's value to `null` in Fauna, it is removed from the object. In your example, assuming `ref` is a valid [Reference](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/fql/functions/ref?lang=javascript):

```
Update(ref, { "2": null })
```

will remove the key `"2"` and its associated value from the object, leaving you with:

```
{ "1": { "name": "test" } }
```

Answer (score 1):

For a bare object, you can use the `Merge` function to remove object keys by setting their value to `null`:

```
> Merge({"1": { "name": "test" }, "2": { "name": "test2" }}, { "2": null })
{ '1': { name: 'test' } }
```